# Issue with getting timezone information with javascript in latest version of firefox (64)

Tags: javascript, firefox

I use the following snippet of code to determine different values related to the timezone reported by the operating system.

```
var oldOffset;
var dstBegin;
var dstEnd;
var dstDuration;
var inDayLightTimeFlag;
var useDayLightTimeFlag;
var arr = [];

var d = new Date();
d.setHours(12,0,0,0);
var currOffset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
var daysInYear = 365;
for(var i=1; i<=daysInYear; i++){
    d = new Date();
    //Defaulting time to 12:00PM each day as DST should have already been observed/no longer observed by that time
    d.setHours(12,0,0,0);
    d.setDate(i);
    var newOffset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
    if(i !== 1 && newOffset != oldOffset){
        if(newOffset < oldOffset){
            dstBegin = i;
        } else if(newOffset > oldOffset) {
            dstEnd = i;
        }
    }
    arr.push(newOffset);
    oldOffset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
}

var DST = Math.min.apply(null,arr);
var nonDST = Math.max.apply(null,arr);
console.log("IN DST Flag: " + inDayLightTimeFlag);
console.log("USE DST Flag: " + useDayLightTimeFlag);
console.log("Duration: " + dstDuration);
console.log("Begin: " + dstBegin);
console.log("End: " + dstEnd);
```

I got this code off another post in stack overflow and it worked fine for a while. But now I am seeing mixed results. It works fine in Chrome, IE, and Edge, but doesn't in Firefox for a certain case.

In the case where I am having trouble, I am setting my computer timezone to US/Central(I am on Windows 10) and unchecking the daylight savings checkbox.

In Chrome/IE/Edge, the values returned from the above code are:

> inDayLightTimeFlag: false
>   useDayLightTimeFlag: false
>   dstDuration: 0
>   dstBegin: 0
>   dstEnd: 0

Which is the correct result in this case.

But in firefox, I get the following values:

> inDayLightTimeFlag: false
>   useDayLightTimeFlag: true
>   dstDuration: 60
>   dstBegin: 69
>   dstEnd: 307

which is wrong. We tested it on different versions of firefox, and it works fine in 62 but the problem starts with 63 and above. It appears to have been caused by this recent change to firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1346211

Any thoughts? Looking for a way to make this as browser independent as possible but it seems that the bug resolution in firefox may have caused more problems.

Comment: I guess the only truly browser-independent way is to just ask the user for his timezone and ship a tz database (e.g. `timezone.js`) with your application

Comment: This is a long-standing problem with, well, the world. We don't have a single method for telling time... What are you doing with the time zone? As @Bergi mentions, the most accurate method is to ask. If you have a `Date` object in a particular time zone and want to format it in another, you could look into [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat), which [appears to be well-supported across browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization).

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I basically get that info and send it over to Java so that I can find the java timezone object for that information. I guess the annoying part is that it worked fine before Firefox 63 was released so now we have to revisit our "solution"